# Next departure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp, real-time

I have a list of daily schedules, and I want to make a script that will indicate in real time the next departure (of a train for example..). If a visitor come on my website, he will see: The next train is leaving at 16h25, in 12mn!

I guess there is something to do with timestamps, but i can't figure out how to do it. :(
Moreover, the schedules are the same everyday, and timestamp will change from day to day, so i'm stuck... If someone can help me, that would be great!!

Thank you!

The code i'm tring to adapt: (this one is working with days, like for announcing next birthdays, but i need to make it work with hours and minutes within a day...)

```
function sched(year,month,date,depart) {
this.year=year
this.month=month
this.date=date
this.depart=depart
}
function schedlist() {
}
blist=new schedlist()
blist[0]= new sched(0000,5,25,"May 25")
blist[1]= new sched(0000,6,8,"Jun 8")
var now=new Date()
today=new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth()+1,now.getDate()) // today 0:00:00
function daysFromToday(sdate) {
return Math.round((sdate.getTime()-today.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000))
}
function writeNextsched(list) {
var daysToClosest=888
var closest
for (var i in list) {
thisDate=new Date(today.getFullYear(),list[i].month,list[i].date)
if (daysFromToday(thisDate)<0)
thisDate.setYear(today.getFullYear()+1)
if (daysFromToday(thisDate)<daysToClosest) {
daysToClosest=daysFromToday(thisDate)
closest=i
}
}
if (daysToClosest==0)
document.write("NOW ! "+list[closest].depart)
else if (daysToClosest==7)
document.write("NEXT WEEK "+list[closest].depart)
else
document.write("Next:"+list[closest].depart)
}
```

Comment: where is the daily schedule list: on sql or file? can you post a sample from it?

Comment: post what have you tried ?

Comment: Thank you! The Daily schedule list would probably be inside the javascript itself... (but any idea about working with MySql would be fine as long as i can make it work...)
The script i try to adapt is now indicated in my first post... ;)

Comment: Indent your code properly please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have your departure times saved as hour and minute.

Now you could use `new Date()` to get the current date and time. With the methods `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` you can get the current hour and minutes.

The only thing to do now is to subtract the values and display them.

If your departure time is an timestamp you can use `new Date(<timestamp>)` to get a date object with the daprture times.

Comment: Yes.. Thank you. But i need to indicate the NEXT departure, not all of them. I'm trying to adapt a script i've been using (see my question post). Thanks for your help...